# 'meteor run android-device' takes forever installing the Cordova plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, deployment, meteor

Is this just a mistake on my system here, but it takes at least 15 minutes or even longer to `"meteor run android-device"`. It hangs at 90% of installing the cordova plugins.

In detail I have 2 cordova-packages *mdg:camera* and *mdg:geolocation* but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

It is getting slow when I add the plugin `plugin.google.maps@1.2.4` which is a native map.

I switched to developing on the browser, and also the google chrome browser developer tools, but sometimes I need to see how it looks on an actual device, and if it runs there for that matters.

Also once it runs it doesn't update any changes or only very slowly.
On the browser everything is ok, loading times, "hot code push".

I thought it would get better with the latest update of meteor announcing the very same thing, but I am already running METEOR@1.0.2.1.

Cannot be my internet connection either, it's 100mbit.

It really seems to be the maps plugin, also as others suggested, it helps (but only a little) to

`rm -rf .meteor/local/cordova-build/
rm -rf .meteor/local/build/`

Is there another way to minimize loading times?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was really the google maps plugin. Since I removed it the deployment is faster now, don't know if it is only in case of this special plugin or a general problem with meteor/cordova.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general problem with the meteor version you are using. It's fixed in Meteor version 1.2.1 and above.

Comment: Nope, problem still persists at 1.4 and above